# Choosing optimal data-points for learning linear decision boundaries

Tags: classification, optimization, linear-model, linear, bayesian-optimization

Consider a high-dimensional linear decision problem with points $\bf x_i \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and corresponding binary labels ${\bf b}_i \in \left\{0,1\right\}$. Assume there is an optimal decision boundary $\bf d$ and bias $\bf b$ such that the decision rule ${\bf d}^\top {\bf x}_i > 0$ perfectly predicts the class label ${\bf b}_i$.

Instead of learning a linear classifier from *given* data-points we are here allowed to *choose* the data-points we want to use for training. In other words, during learning we are allowed to choose the points ${\bf x}_i$ and are given the corresponding label ${\bf b}_i$ for each point.

**Question:** What is the optimal strategy to estimate the decision boundary from a minimum set of optimally chosen data-points?